# LogLikelihood and MultinomialDistribution in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, multinomial, log-likelihood

can someone explain to me why the following code

> LogLikelihood[  MultinomialDistribution[   countstot, {dt1/ttot,
>   dt2/ttot, dt3/ttot, dt4/ttot,     dt5/ttot}], {CR1, CR2, CR3, CR4,
>   CR5}]

does not produce a number as output, but instead this:

> LogLikelihood[  MultinomialDistribution[   156, {318/1049, 159/1049,
>   208/1049, 222/1049, 142/1049}], {0.00186, 
>     0.00185, 0.00136, 0.00108, 0.00115}]

it is the first time I use LogLikelihood and MultinomialDistribution, and I have probably done something wrong, but I can't really understand what.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a few clues from the documentation.

```
d = MultinomialDistribution[
    156, {318/1049, 159/1049, 208/1049, 222/1049, 142/1049}] // N;
```

These are the mean results expected from this distribution

```
m = Mean[d]
```

> {47.2908, 23.6454, 30.9323, 33.0143, 21.1173}

```
Total[m]
```

> 156.

Taking some random values

```
r = RandomVariate[d]
```

> {51, 17, 23, 41, 24}

The log-likelihood of these values  (non-negative integer input for multinomial)

```
LogLikelihood[d, {r}]
```

> -12.9418

```
Total[r]
```

> 156

Scaling up your figures and rounding so that they total 156

```
values  = {0.00186, 0.00185, 0.00136, 0.00108, 0.00115};
factor  = 156/Total[values];
scaled  = 0.999 factor values;
rounded = Round[scaled]
```

> {40, 39, 29, 23, 25}

```
Total[rounded]
```

> 156

```
LogLikelihood[d, {rounded}]
```

> -16.555